# ethereum node to setup with min space

Tags: nodes

i want to setup an ethereum node for my website to use. What is the min space I need? To save space do I need to use light node? Or even Better idea?
How much space I need for light node or full node? Or some other node I can only keep the transactions related to myself?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a > 200 GB SSD hard drive to sync a full Ethereum node these days.
This would be possible, but expensive, to run on AWS or some other cloud provider.

I don't have the numbers for a light node, but it would be a more reasonable number.

You can't choose which transactions are kept on a node, but if you're interested in indexing only your contract data for efficiency reasons, you can emit solidity events / EVM  logs and set up a Subgraph
https://thegraph.com

You can run your own subgraph server to power your website / front-end.